# How to write an HTTP client library to a Micronaut service?

Tags: micronaut

I'm writing a Micronaut Service, and I would like to provide a Java client library to access my service, using the [low-level](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#lowLevelHttpClient) and/or the [declarative](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientAnnotation) HTTP client featured in Micronaut.

It works fine as long as the client code is colocated to the controller code, but if I isolate the client code from the server code in two separated Gradle (or Maven) modules I have injection dependency errors: I guess that the controller and the client must be in the same application context.

I know that I can use any language with any HTTP library to write such a client, but  i'd like to stick with the Micronaut API and annotations.

Am I missing something or am I wrong with my thinking?

My client:

```
@Client("/hello")
public interface HelloClient {

    @Get
    Single<String> hello();
}
```

My test:

```
public class HelloClientSpec {

    @Inject
    HelloClient client;

    @Test
    public void testHelloWorldResponse() {
        assertEquals("Hello World", client.hello().blockingGet());
    }
}
```

My error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.company.client.OverlandClientSpec.testHelloWorldResponse(OverlandClientSpec.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:515)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Basically, it's saying that the injected client object is null.

Comment: can you please post the full error message in OP?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: HelloClientSpec is that your entire test? Is it annotated with `@MicronautTest` ?

Comment: "I guess that the controller and the client must be in the same application context." Definitely not the case

Comment: One educated guess is that the project which you moved the client into does not have the required annotation processors available at compile time.  Another is that you aren't merging the service descriptors.

Comment: OK, the issue was due to the missing annotation processors at compile time. Great! But now, Micronaut picks a random port number for the Netty HTTP client and I had to set the whole service URL with @Client(value = "http://localhost:8080/hello"). How can I pass host and port in configuration instead?

Comment: That is an entirely different question.  When the service is started, Micronaut will respect the `micronaut.server.port` config setting which can be set in `application.yml` (`application.groovy` if you are using Groovy config), a system property named `micronaut.server.port` or an environment variable named `MICRONAUT_SERVER_PORT`.  See https://docs.micronaut.io/1.1.0/guide/index.html#runningSpecificPort.